# How to change permit parameter before saving in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the next code:

```
permitted = params.permit(:url, :title, :description, :post_type, :category_id)
```

and I want to change params[:url] before saving process. I did try:

```
params[:url] = "abc"
```

but it didn't change this value. How can I catch and change it before saving? It's into feed controller. I also tried:

```
params[:feed][:url]
```

but again nothing. Can anyone gives me some tips?

Comment: based on your `pemit` statement it would be `params[:url]` but I would suggest actually looking at the structure of the `params`. `param` is simply a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` this means that `params[:url] = "abc"` will overwrite  `params[:url]` without issue. Your problem seems to lie with the fact that you are not overwriting in the correct space.

Comment: @engineersmnky Oh, I have the next problem: `regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/ givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0] newUrl = givenUrl.split('.be/')[1]` these code give me the result. But when I try to save it `params[:url] = newUrl` I get an error, `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` for the `givenUrl`. What is the problem?

Comment: That is because `params` is not passing just `url` it is probably something like `params[:feed][:url]` but without seeing the raw params or the form i cannot say this with any certainty.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the model with permitted parameters, then change any of them how you wish:

```
m = Model.new(permitted)
m.url = "abc"
m.save
```

Comment: Oh, I have the next problem: `regex = /(?:.be\/|\/watch\?v=|\/(?=p\/))([\w\/\-]+)/ givenUrl = params[:url].match(regex)[0] newUrl = givenUrl.split('.be/')[1]` these code give me the result. But when I try to save it `params[:url] = newUrl` I get an error, `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` for the `givenUrl`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following ways, depending on what I need.

#### [`before_save` callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Define in your model. Good when there is a general rule on what data should be in the given field. In most other cases too, actually, but that's slightly more complicated.

#### `params.require(...).permit(...).merge(url: 'whatever')`

This takes your parameters and writes (overwriting) the ones given inside `merge`. It doesn't have to be one key-value pair. I use that sometimes for writing in timestamps. It's a rather clean trick, but `befoe_save` should be favored: I only use it when I don't think writing a separate one-use-case method on a model is worth it.

Comment: @Orkhan ask another question then. StackOverflow works on a "topic per question" rule.